# Google app displaying temperature in Fahrenheit

Tags: applications, google

When I use widget for voice search and say 'weather' I get the results, but it is shown in Fahrenheit, even though,in settings it is chosen to show in Celsius.

Any solution?

Comment: Pull down from one of the Os in the Google logo in the Google now app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem apparently is due to the device language selection.

If English (US) is chosen, Google defaults to temperature units used in US (Fahrenheit)

This is remedied by switching over to English (UK), where temperature units are in Celsius

**Source:** [Accepted answer on Android wear,How do I change temperature units in Android wear weather app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/132909/131553)

Comment: This will have the side affect of breaking movie titles in the Google TV app.  Only English US shows English titles and proper thumbnails.  I was using English (CA).

Comment: This isn't a solution at all. Temperature units aren't the only difference between English US and English UK.

Answer (score 14):

The other answer on this question didn't work for me. My phone was already on English (UK) and changing it to US and back did not help.

Instead what fixed it for me was:

1. Open the Google app.
2. Scroll down to the Weather card.
3. Press the menu button on that card.
4. Press "Change temperature units to °F".
5. Press the menu again.
6. Press "Change temperature units to °C".

Comment: This worked for me! Even with English (US) settings.

Answer (score 3):

Double click the At a glance banner (the temperature), an app will pop up where you can change the setting at the upper left corner

Answer (score 2):

Long-tap on the home screen and go to "Select Widgets". Under Google, select the "At a Glance" widget and drag it to the home screen.

For me, this changed the unit from F to C instantly.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. This actually did the trick for me as well, where nothing else was working. I added the widget again, and it changed it to Celsius for both of them, after which you can remove the duplicate widget.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Android, just ask Google Assistant to change it from F to C permanently. It works for me. Google Assistant will say "I will remember your preference".

Answer (score 1):

Touch the little red 'F' to the upper right of the days temperature (that's in big black bold numbers) next to the big numbers at the upper right.

There is a little blue 'C' for Celsius then a slash and a little red 'F' for Fahrenheit, and it will switch back to Fahrenheit or Celcius by touching either one of those little letters.